# Show a custom URL in the header on a WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to achieve a customized url that shows in url header. Different for every WordPress post.

For example, I have posts in WordPress about different countries what I want is that when I click on a country the single post page which normally shows up like this in the browser url field:

www.example.com/2017/11/china

Should show up like this, only in header like.

china.example.com or
russia.example.com

I don't know if I can achieve this using WordPress or Do I have to play around with .htaccess file.

There are more than 200 posts and I am trying to find a way to do it using an automated script or WordPress code.

I want this link to be associated with the actual post on the WordPress site. Please let me know if it's achievable or if there is already a post on stack overflow that solves this. I couldn't find one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

china.example.com is a subdomain, example.com/.../china is a folder.  They are actually two different things.  To achieve this effect though, you would need to set up a multi-site wordpress installation, and treat china.example.com as one website and russia.example.com as another

Comment: Note, if you have a bunch of posts where it is only a couple to a region, this is probably not the optimal solution. SEO, DNS servers, etc view this format "china.example.com" as a completely separate website from example.com and may not be a good idea.  Instead you could sort them by categories or parent/child pages in your URL to show up as example.com/china/mypost